# How to invoke a method only while button is pressed?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a voice command button that works with while pressed. I have 2 methods, one button calls the first method which starts recording, the 2nd stops the recording. How can i make it so that i use one button (while pressed) or for example 1 method on press the 2nd method on button release? I don't know what to use.

Comment: You could keep a flag and set it when the button is pressed. If flag is set, you call the function to stop recording and if it is not, you call the function to start it. (Like this, you don't have to keep the button pressed while recording).

Comment: the idea is that i want the button to be pressed while recording. Also i don't understand the flag issue. If the flag is set to false, then true when i first press, how would it be turned back to false and autostop recording?

Comment: What do you mean by 'autostop' recording? If you want the button to be pressed for entire duration of recording, answers added below are correct. I personally find it annoying to hold the button while recording, so I suggested this. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `GestureDetector` as your widget and use `onLongPressUp` and `onLongPressStart` respectively

```
GestureDetector(
  onLongPressStart: _startRec, // start recording when long pressed
  onLongPressUp: _stopRec, // stop recording when released
  child: Text("Hold to record"),
);
```